# Writing to a file in loop doesn't work

Tags: java, io, filewriter

I want to open a file, write it in a loop (append everything to the previous lines) and then close it. I had already implmented everything in a single method inside the loop and I had a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505718/writing-a-java-file-need-it-to-be-cleared-each-run). So, I'm trying to implement it according to the suggestion that writing and opening must be done in different steps. My code now is like the following:

```
  PrintWriter out=  createAndOpenFile(fileName);

     for (int i = 0 ; i< test.size(); i++){
             writeToFile(mystring, out);
        }
    out.close();
```

And the implementation of the above methods are like the following:

```
  private PrintWriter createAndOpenFile(String fileName) {

        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
          return out;

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

 private void writeToFile(String features, PrintWriter out) {
       out.println(features);
       out.flush();
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Update: With "not working" I meant that the file is empty at the end, though created.

Comment: And "does not work" means what?

Comment: The file is empty at the end, though created.

Comment: Hm, ok. But you know that you're using an auto-closable in `createAndOpenFile`?

Comment: @AKSW What do you mean by auto-closable?

Comment: `createAndOpenFile` returns a writer that is already closed, because it uses a try-with-resources. Anywhere outside of the `try(...) { ... }` block, the writer is closed.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html for try with resources.

Comment: Returning inside the `try` is an example of abrupt completion, as defined by [JLS 14.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @khelwood says, `out` is closed at the return statement. That's expected.

If you do the `writeToFile`'s inside the `try`, it works (the file will not be empty):

```
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("c:/temp/tt.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
        writeToFile(mystring, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```